# Strange noise only when accelerating in Peugeot 301

Tags: automatic-transmission, peugeot, knock, peugeot-301

A variant of Peugeot 301 with naturally aspirated engine and DAE 6 speed AT.

only if the car has warmed and only when accelerating, there is a knocking noise frequency around 1Hz at 60kph and increasing at higher speeds. No shaking, no powerless no other noise

When moving if put in neutral or not pressing accelerator pedal, there is no noise.

Recently changed faulty shock absorbers maybe the noise started after that not sure.

No one could be able to give a good diagnosis

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!